Custom PrintService Android app is not listed in playstore under print service apps
For listing a Custom PrintService Android app under print services in Google Play Store, is there any criteria to satisfy, other than service & resource entry in the Manifest (Reference link).
App is not listed under print-service category in Google Play Store Android app: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=print-service&c=apps
I was following below steps to see my app in the print-service list

Pick a file and hit 'Print'
From Print dialog, hit 'Add Printer'
From the popup, hit 'All services'
This opens the Google Play Store with print-service apps list, where my app is not listed.



Thanks in advance.
Manifest entry:
<service
android:name=".CustomPrintService"
android:exported="true"
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_PRINT_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.printservice.PrintService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.printservice"
            android:resource="@xml/printservice" />
    </service>

PrintService.xml
<print-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:vendor="Vendor"
android:settingsActivity=".SettingsActivity"
android:addPrintersActivity=".AddPrintersActivity"
android:advancedPrintOptionsActivity="PrintOptionsActivity" />

